# Vue data being stored in vuex but not displaying in the UI

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am trying to get some plan data to show up in my Vue application. The data is loaded via an API I have running locally. I have figured out how to add the data to the store/vuex and vue dev tools shows it is good however I am unable to see the data in the UI. I am looking for help on solving why the data is not showing in the UI.

In my `plans.vue` I just do a for loop over the `plans` data and it works if I manually put the data into the array so somewhere between the store and the data prop it is broken.

store.js

```
state: {
 plans: []
}
mutations: {
  loadPlans(state, plans) {
     state.plans = plans
 }
},
getters: {
    loadPlans(state) {
      return state.plans
    },
}
```

plans.vue

```
created() {
        PageOptions.pageEmpty = true;
        this.$store.dispatch('loadPlans')
    },
    data() {
        return {
            plans: this.$store.getters.loadPlans,
        }
    },
```

This is striped down to include just the code used for this issue, there is a ton more code that isn't related to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with something like this:

*store.js*

```
state: {
  plans: []
},
getters: {
  loadedPlans(state) {
    return state.plans
  },
},
mutations: {
  setPlans(state, plans) {
    state.plans = plans
  }
},
actions: {
  async loadPlans({commit}) {
    await this.$axios.get('http://localhost/api/plans', function(response) {
      commit('setPlans', response.data)
    })
  }
}
```

*plans.vue*

```
async created() {
  await this.$store.dispatch('loadPlans')
},
computed: {
  myPlans() {
    return this.$store.getters.loadedPlans
  }
}
```

Comment: Can I change that to not use async await in the created portion? I have something in created that can't be done async

Comment: yes, you could also use `$store.getters.loadedPlans` directly in the component but with async await is better, try to refactor the rest of your code making it fully async

Comment: Okay so I tried your way with everything except the async await on created and it does the exact name thing, it fills in the state and it doesn't load in the UI. When I do a console.log on the created just after the store dispatch it returns null so no data is being passed to the data prop.

Comment: "loadPlans" is a promise, that's why you should await the axios callback that will commit "setPlans"; try to put the console.log this.$store.dispatch('loadPlans').then(() => { /* here */ })

Comment: This ended up being the closest to the solution I went with, marking as solved

Answer (score 0):

you can use a computed method for getting the value. The data object is evaluated once even perhaps before the state value is set. Modify your code as follows.

```
data:{
    return {};
}
,computed: {
    plans: this.$store.getters.loadPlans
}
```

Comment: Just gave that a try, it breaks it badly, nothing loads

Comment: "The data object is evaluated once even perhaps before the state value is set" is right, that's why you should use a computed method